# how to test aspx page behaviour when multiple requests(~50) are made simultaneously using visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I have to test my asp.net web application for performance when there are simultaneous requests for the web site in my developer machine before deploy in production. how can i achieve this using Visual Studio?.(without using third party tools preferably Visual studio 2010 professional edition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned you only want to use Visual Studio but real benchmarking tools have very little to do with your IDE.

[WCAT](http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1467) is quite useful.

I recommend of course you try this on a development or staging server, don't even think about trying this in a live environment!

Answer (score 1):

If you [look here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products) you'll note that load testing doesn't come with VS 2010 Professional.

Since you've removed Third Party tools you're left with rolling your own. This will require that use threads to make calls to your web app via the HttpRequest object.

Rolling your own would likely cost your business more than what your time costs.

Answer (score 1):

I'd note that load testing on your developer machine tells you squat in most cases. The environment is vastly different enough that the only thing you can usually figure out is "do we have a race condition here with more than one simultaneous request to this app?"

Best bet is to use a real load testing tool or service on a setup that mirrors your production environment as much as possible. For new apps, consider using the production environment before you go live for this.

I'll also note you should use a third party tool over rolling your own.